# I cant use subprocess.call() [AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'call']

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use a function (subprocess.call()) using "import subprocess" but when i run the code it gives me an error

```
import os
import subprocess

a = open(os.devnull,'w')
p = subprocess.call(['ping','-c','2','1.1.1.1'],stdout=a,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
if p == 1:
    print("El comando se ejecuto correctamente")
else:
    print("Falló la ejecucion del comando")
```

**AttributeError:  module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'call'**

Comment: What version of python are you running? Generally, it's recommended in modern versions of python to use `subprocess.run()` over `subprocess.call()` - try that and see if it works

Comment: Python 3.7.3 - It works with subprocess.run(), thanks :)